# How to using bruteforce method list al possible combinations of an element?

Tags: php, algorithm, brute-force

How to list all possible combinations of:

String (4 characters, only lowercase no numbers or special signs), # sign, String (5 chars, the same rue as for the 1st).

e.g.:

dhgi#msodd

Comment: why do you need this? what are you trying to do?

Comment: @SilentGhost: He's trying to do [the same thing as yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874256/list-all-possible-combinations-of-letters-8-up-to-64-bit-long-string), just tricking us with asking for an extraneous hash this time.

Comment: @mario: It wasn't clear to **why** he's doing this yesterday too.

Comment: This has got homework written all over it imo.

Comment: @Neil - even teachers don't generally set such stupid homework as this. Personally, I think he's a script kiddie wannabee... look at previous questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863029/how-to-extract-text-from-an-image-using-php for how to crack a captcha

Comment: @SilentGhost: I'm assuming it's about his original [URL shortening question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862802/php-implementation-for-an-url-shortening-algorithm). Maybe Google blocks [search results](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+url+shortening+script) about that for him.

Comment: @Mark I would not want to be him.  Looks like his approach to everything is brute force, including his approach to programming.

Comment: @Neil - It's why I'm happy to give a brute-force answer. If his approach is always going to be brute force, rather than real hacking, he's one less threat to any of my sites

Answer (score 6):

Assumption: English alphabet

```
for($firstPart = 'aaaa'; $firstPart != 'aaaaa'; $firstPart++) {
   for($secondPart = 'aaaaa'; $secondPart != 'aaaaaa'; $secondPart++) {
      echo $firstPart,'#',$secondPart,'<br />';
   }
}
```

Though why you'd want to do this, I don't know.

Is this related to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874256/list-all-possible-combinations-of-letters-8-up-to-64-bit-long-string)?

Answer (score 0):

powered by recursion

```
  function bruteforce($data)
{
    $storage = array();
    tryCombination($data,'',$storage);
    return $storage;
}


function tryCombination($input,$output,&$storage)
{
    if($input == "")
    {

        if(!in_array($output,$storage))
        array_push($storage,$output);

    }else {
        for($i = 0 ; $i < strlen($input) ; $i++)
        {
            $next = $output  . $input[$i];
            $remaining = substr($input,0,$i)  . substr($input,$i + 1);
            tryCombination($remaining,$next,$storage);
        }
    }


}

$final = bruteforce('yourData');
echo count($final);
print_r($final);
```